# Swift how to create class instance from string originating in lib

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to create a a swift class from a string reference to its class name

I am able to get a Type however I am not sure how to go form AnyClass to an initialized instance

```
let className: String = "myLibDomain.className"
if let referencedClass = NSClassFromString(className){
    if let conformantReferanceClass = referencedClass as? myProtocol {
        //do some work defined by myProtocol
    }
}
```

NSClassFromSting returns me something of type AnyClass and in the debugger it looks something like this:
myLibDomain.className
it does not have memory allocated, I believe I'm missing a step. There is no init() method for AnyClass

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by modifying line 2 to look like this:

```
if let referencedClass = NSClassFromString(className)?.alloc()
```

Does this look reasonable? I've never used that keyword in swift, i was looking at some objective c solutions to the same issue. NOTE: the 'referancedClass' in the example I am working with does not inherit from NSObject